# Spring MVC Initializing Twice in Google AppEngine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

This question is already asked and i have checked all the solutions, but nothing helped me, am still facing the same issue.

I have configured My Google Appengine Project To Use Spring MVC Using Java Config, and i set the logging level for spring as INFO to check the initialization log.

This is what am getting upon initialization,

```
    14:52:37,885 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'SpringMvcConfig': initialization started
14:52:37,885 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'SpringMvcConfig': initialization started
14:52:37,927 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringMvcConfig-servlet': startup date [Sun Sep 08 14:52:37 UTC 2013]; root of context hierarchy
14:52:37,927 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringMvcConfig-servlet': startup date [Sun Sep 08 14:52:37 UTC 2013]; root of context hierarchy
14:52:38,087 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
14:52:38,087 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
14:52:38,093 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] - Successfully resolved class for [com.test.config.SpringMvcConfig]
14:52:38,093 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] - Successfully resolved class for [com.test.config.SpringMvcConfig]
14:52:38,239 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
14:52:38,239 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
14:52:38,826 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
14:52:38,826 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
14:52:38,987 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7fa6e654: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,springMvcConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,mainController,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcContentNegotiationManager,mvcConversionService,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcValidator,httpRequestHandler  Adapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,getInternalResourceViewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
14:52:38,987 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7fa6e654: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,springMvcConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,mainController,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcContentNegotiationManager,mvcConversionService,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcValidator,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,getInternalResourceViewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
14:52:39,378 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Mapped "{[/ || /login],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto java.lang.String com.test.controller.MainController.hanldeRequest()
14:52:39,378 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Mapped "{[/ || /login],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto java.lang.String com.test.controller.MainController.hanldeRequest()
14:52:39,449 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
14:52:39,449 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
14:52:40,355 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'SpringMvcConfig': initialization completed in 2468 ms
14:52:40,355 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'SpringMvcConfig': initialization completed in 2468 ms
```

spring mvc is initialized twice, following is my configuration

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMvcConfig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            com.test.config.SpringMvcConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMvcConfig</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and My Spring MVC Configuration looks like this,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.test.controller")
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true).ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                .useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new CustomJacksonObjectMapper());
        converters.add(converter);
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setCache(false);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Any Solution or suggestion would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full log, please?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the message being logged twice? It seems highly suspicious (to me) that both startup times are identical.

Comment: I have edited this question with full log!

Comment: ya i too thought that, but how will the spring framework log twice? is  there any chance that can happen?

Comment: Have you configured logging? If so, how?

Comment: just a note , in the following post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206564/spring-mvc-two-instances-of-configuration-instead-of-one?rq=1

the problem solved by creating two configuration, but that too dint work for me

Comment: ya using log4j by following configuration

`log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.org.springframework = INFO, A1`

Answer (score 1):

If we look at your log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1 

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n 

log4j.logger.org.apache = WARN, A1 
log4j.logger.org.springframework = INFO, A1
```

Both the logger for `org.springframework` and the `root` logger are configured to use the `A1` appender. If you don't set the [`additivity`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) flag to `false`, they will both append.

> Appender Additivity
>
> The output of a log statement of logger C will go
>   to all the appenders in C and its ancestors. This is the meaning of
>   the term "appender additivity".

However, if an ancestor of logger C, say P, has the additivity flag set to false, then C's output will be directed to all the appenders in C and its ancestors upto and including P but not the appenders in any of the ancestors of P.

Loggers have their additivity flag set to true by default.

```
log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false
```

Either do that or remove the `A1` appender from the `rootLogger`

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a very similar problem in tomcat because the context was being loaded twice.  once by a context load listener (to configure a servlet filter) and once by the dispatch servlet.  so i wonder if you are doing something similar?

in other words, some things in spring load contexts by default.  try disabling the explicit loading of context and see what happens.

in my case, the solution was to separate the contexts - have different contexts for the filter and servlet.  then each was loaded correctly without overlap.

edit: hmm, expanding comments i see you've found a similar answer.  i'd encourage you to follow that up more closely.  you really need to work out what is loading the extra context.  look for context files with "special" names (eg named after a servlet or similar).  then try changing their names, for example.  in short - you need to find / break the auto-load.