# Unable to configure RootConfig and RootWebMvcConfig

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to configure a Spring app with two servlets:

1. regular web servlet that uses Spring's transaction management with
   JPA;
2. a DispatcherServlet for serving up REST endpoints, which also
   requires the same transaction management.

My current configuration below matches the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14207953)** with the exception of one thing. In the RootWebMvcConfig, I have imported the RootConfig. I understand this is the cause of the error message I'm receiving below, however I would like to understand how to configure this so that both my web servlet and REST servlet have access to the root config. If I omit the import, I receive exceptions indicating there is no session in progress when accessing the REST endpoint through the DispatcherServlet.

HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'

Any suggestions on how to configure this so that both my web servlet and REST servlet have access to the root config?

Example web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.RootConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package.RootWebMvcConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>anotherservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.AnotherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>anotherservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And example config classes:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.package"})
@Import(value = {PersistenceConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
public class RootConfig {
    ...
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"my.package.repository"})
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
    ...

}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.package"})
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(value = {RootConfig.class})
public class RootWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

The service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MyProjectProvider {

    @Autowired
    private EntityToRestPojoMapper mapper; // This is an Orika ConfigurableMapper
    @Autowired
    private MyObjectService service;

    public List<MyObjectPojo> getMyObjects() {
        List<MyObject> data = service.findData();       
        List<MyObjectPojo> dataPojos = new ArrayList<MyObjectPojo>();
        mapper.mapAsCollection(data, dataPojos, MyObjectPojo.class);
        return dataPojos;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to import RootConfig from RootWebMvcConfig. Upd oops miaread the question, I would move the transactional services to the root web app context instead.

Comment: Also please note that the servlet context will already have access to the beans in the root web app context defined by RootConfig because of the web app context hierarchy  in Spring.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code of the method where transaction is not available.